# Handling 204- No Content response in HTTP Observable - Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http, angular2-observables

In my Angular2 application, I am taking responses from a REST API and manipulating them in order to display them in the user interface.

I coded my application according to following tutorial.

https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/04/02/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/

*This is my method to get the response from server*

```
getTendersByCategory(categoryName: string){

        console.log("get tenders by category "+categoryName);

        let tendersByCategory = this._http
            .get(this._endpointUrl + "tender/get-by-category-name/" + categoryName)
            .map(mapTenders)
            .catch(handleError);

        return tendersByCategory;

}
```

Following functions are used to manipulate the response

```
function mapTenders(response: Response): Tender[] {
    console.log('tender.service.ts -> mapTenders');

    /*if(response.status == 204){
        console.log("response = 204 - No content in response");
        return null;
    }*/

    return response.json().map(toTender);
}


function toTender(r: any): Tender {
    console.log('tender.service.ts -> toTender');
    let tender = <Tender>({
        id: r.id,
        name: r.name,
        publisher: r.publisher,
    });
    return tender;
}

function handleError(error: any) {
    console.error(error.message);
    return Observable.throw(error.message);
}
```

The problem now is, I get 204 - No content response for my requests. In those cases, I get the error

> Cannot read property 'map' of null

What I have tried up to now is, I check whether the response is 204 in my `mapTenders` function; if so I return null without proceeding with mapping to my object. (This part of code has been commented out in the given code)

Is that the correct way of handing this response?

But in that case, even though I get rid of the error, in my `.component.ts` file I do not get an empty list of tenders. It shows all the tenders without any sort of filtering. (That may be the result from refreshing the entire page, but apparently, page does not reload.)

This is the method in my component.ts file.

```
getTendersByCategory(categoryName: string){

        this._tendersService.getTendersByCategory(categoryName).
            subscribe(

            tenders => this._tenders = tenders,
            error => this._error_tender = error

            );

       console.log("tenders.component.ts.getTendersByCategory -> tenders array = "+this._tenders.length);

       //for debugging purpose
       //this prints all the tenders. What I wished to see is nothing getting printed
       for(let i=0; i< this._tenders.length;i++){
           printTender(this._tenders[i]);
       }

    }
```

What can I do here? How should I handle 204 response when using observables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the Error Response in service call itself.Try the below code

```
MethodName(searchLetter: string, gender: string): Observable<Object[]> {
            let dataUrl = 'this._endpointUrl/tender/get-by-category-name/';
            let params = new URLSearchParams;
            params.append('categoryName', categoryName);
            let headers = new Headers();

            return this.http.get(dataUrl, { headers: headers, search: params })
                .map(response =>  { 
                // If request fails, throw an Error that will be caught 
                if(response.status != 200) { 
                throw new Error('This request has failed ' + res.status); } // If everything went fine, return the response 
                else {
                 return response.json(); 
                } }).catch(this.handleError);
        }
```

Comment: How can I do it in my service, because I have a different code ` this._http
            .get(this._endpointUrl + "tender/get-by-category-name/" + categoryName)
            .map(mapTenders)
            .catch(handleError);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can u suggest me a solution for my case. I am calling an external function to map the objects I receive

Comment: Remove the external function and try the observable object in the same function

Comment: Hi, I am accepting this as the answer, Sorry it got some time to understand the whole thing. However, I did not remove my mapping function. It is still there

Comment: I think it's better to filter empty responses or pass null in such cases...
This solution (throw if not 200) is definitely not acceptable. There are other HTTP responses that contain a body (e.g. 201 Created).

So ignoring other successful responses (generally) is a bad idea. (As well as the fact you treat successful 2xx responses as errors)